# Are equilibrium states at fixed U and at fixed S the same state?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

Consider a closed (which doesn't exchange matter with its surrounding) system initially in an equilibrium state $(S_a,U_a,V_a)$ with $U_a$, $V_a$ fixed by some external constraints.
The constraint restrictive with respect to the volume is removed, thus the system can evolve and reach a final equilibrium state. Let $(S_b,U_a,V_b)$ the parameters at the final equilibrium state.

Now consider the same system initially in the equilibrium state $(S_b,U_c,V_c)$ with $S_b$, $V_c$ fixed by some external constraints.
Again, the constraint restrictive with respect to the volume is removed, and the system reaches the final equilibrium state $(S_b,U_d,V_d)$.

Now the question: is it obvious that $U_a=U_d$ and $V_b=V_d$, that is to say is it obvious that the two final equilibrium states are actually the same equilibrium state?

PS: I'm trying to understand Callen's proof of the equivalence between the entropy maximum principle and the energy minimum principle (page 134). To show the implication to the right, he uses the entropy maximum principle while $U$ isn't constant, which I don't understand. However, if the final state at $S$ constant is the same as the one at $U$ constant, the proof works, hence my question.

Comment: Can you  narrow things down a bit about the nature of the system. Is the  system open or closed, that is, can the system exchange mass with its surroundings? Can we assume the two processes involved are either adiabatic or not?

Comment: Also, is there any additional context or motivation associated wth the question?

Comment: The system is closed, and the processes aren't adiabatic a priori (the second can be to make S constant). I edited the question, added the PS and the fact that the system is closed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the system  and the context of your question. It is still  complex, so  it might take some time, at least for me, to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not obvious, and in fact it is not true.  Consider the case of an ideal gas, for which the internal energy is simply proportional to the temperature.  Your first process, in which the internal energy is fixed but the entropy is permitted to vary, is isothermal expansion (or compression).  The second case, in which the entropy is fixed by the internal energy is permitted to vary, is adiabatic expansion (or compression).  The final states are of course different, which can be seen by the fact that if the internal energy varies then the temperature changes.

I think you are missing the essential point of the argument. Per Callen,

> **Entropy Maximum Principle:** The equilibrium value of any unconstrained internal parameter is such as to maximize the entropy for the given value of the internal energy.
>
> **Energy Minimum Principle:** The equilibrium value of any unconstrained internal parameter is such as to minimize the energy for the given value of the total entropy.

He argues the following: let a system be in equilibrium with internal energy $U_0$ and entropy $S_0$.  Assume the entropy maximum principle is true, so the entropy is maximized at this particular value of the internal energy.  In other words, if the internal energy is $U_0$, then it's not possible to have an entropy higher than $S_0$.  We now seek to show that this implies the energy minimum principle.

Assume that the energy minimum principle does *not* hold - that is, it is possible to decrease $U$ without changing $S$.  If that is the case, then we could extract that energy as work while keeping $S=S_0$ fixed, and then add that energy right back as heat.  If we do this, then the internal energy will once again be $U_0$, but the entropy will be larger than it was when we started, because $dS \geq \frac{Q}{T}$.  But this contradicts our assumption that $S_0$ is the maximum entropy consistent with internal energy $U_0$.  Therefore, it follows that it must *not* be possible to decrease $U$ without changing $S$, and so the entropy maximum principle implies the energy minimum principle.

---

I believe I understand the confusion.  You are envisioning the piston being locked at point $A$ on [your diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTMin.jpg).  From there, you imagine unlocking the piston and taking it along the path to points $B$ and $C$. Is that right?

If so, then the problem comes when you unlock the cylinder.  When you do, one of two things is going to happen:

1. Nothing happens, because the pressure in the cylinder is already equal to the external pressure, so the lock on the cylinder was not actually necessary to maintain the state of the system.  In this case, the system already satisfied the entropy maximum principle *despite* the constraint on $V$.
2. The system is not in a state of equilibrium (the internal pressure is not equal to the external pressure), meaning that it rapidly undergoes a (non quasi-static) transition to a new equilibrium which *does* satisfy the entropy maximum principle.

In the first case, all of the arguments above apply.  The initial constraint on the volume is essentially irrelevant.  In the second case, $A$ would not be the starting point for your process. In either case, the starting point for a process like the one described by Callen is necessarily unconstrained.

Comment: I got that, but you could have an initial equilibrium state where the entropy maximum principle doesn't hold, for instance if you fix the entropy and the volume by some constraints. Then you decrease $U$ with work and increase it with heat, so you end up with a final state where $S>S_0$ and $U=U_0$, but this doesn't contradict the entropy maximum principle since it didn't hold!

Comment: @Jonk  If you're going to allow work and add heat, then you need to remove the constraints on the volume and entropy respectively, so I'm not sure what you're saying here.  You can start with e.g. a gas in an insulated, locked cylinder - then everything is fixed and nothing can change.  The entropy maximum principle is trivially satisfied because there are no unconstrained parameters to vary.  If you unlock the piston, then the system will find a new equilibrium which satisfies the minimum energy principle; if you put the system in thermal contact with a reservoir, then the system will [...]

Comment: [...] find a new equilibrium which satisfies the maximum entropy principle.

Comment: @J.Murray  Not sure that the first process needs to be isothermal. There is also the possibility of the free adiabatic expansion of a gas into a vacuum. It is an irreversible process generating entropy. Volume increases but there is no PdV work, Q=0, and thus $\Delta U=0$.

Comment: @BobD In general, yes I agree.  However, because I specified the ideal gas as an example system, $\Delta U =0 \iff \Delta T = 0$, so an adiabatic expansion into vacuum is also isothermal.

Comment: @J.Murray I agree with you. However, to me, you can't say that the initial system should have had a higher entropy since everything was fixed initially, so there's no contradiction. For instance, the process [here](https://imgur.com/a/alGwcib) is possible, right? We extract energy as work with $S$ constant from A to B, then add it back as work from B to C, with constant $V$. Energy and entropy principles are verified, respectively from A to B and B to C. The system is in equilibrium at A since $V$ and $U$ are fixed by some constraints (like for a gas in an insulated, locked cylinder). [...]

Comment: [...] A and C have the same internal energy, but C has a higher entropy, which isn't a problem here. So we can't conclude that there's a contradiction in the proof! What am I missing?

Comment: @Jonk Please see my edit, I think I know the problem.

Comment: Okay so the entropy maximum principle and energy minimum principle hold only if the initial state is unconstrained. However, is it possible to carry out the process from A to B by holding the piston during all the process? (The volume is constantly defined by the constraint imposed by the operator)

Comment: @Jonk No, those principles always hold. Note that they say that the entropy and energy are maximized and minimized with respect to variations in unconstrained parameters, specifically. If the piston is locked, then those quantities will be extremized subject to the constraint of constant volume.  Yes, that is possible, but in that case you are just varying the external pressure, not constraining the volume to be constant.